# Updated FAQ to reflect latest feedback from the community to increase the type and quality of questions

Tags: discussion, faq-discussion

[This is taken from my answer to a question about my moderation skills.](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/196/93) I noted in my answer that I updated the FAQ to make it more relevant, but I wanted to post a proper question for review. Please see the related discussions elsewhere on this meta with answers from Jeff Atwood and others with more experience (here and in other SE sites):

- [How simple is too simple?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/how-simple-is-too-simple/146#146)
- [How should we rephrase "no ultra simple questions" into the FAQ?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/110/93)
- [Should "Photoshop Users" be its own SE site?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/192/93)

There has been a growing consensus on this site in recent weeks that the questions found here really needs to move more towards questions about graphic design itself—the culture, business, and principles; "more 'why' type of questions on design theories, and even on the graphic design history"—and away from quick tutorial and brainstorming questions like the ones you pointed out. The site is still in beta therefore it is open to changes in guiding principles the community, as a whole, sorts itself out.

I think it is important to not that none of the moderators here take their job lightly, especially updating the FAQ. Continued feedback is extremely helpful as we try to sort where the line is between appropriate or desired vs. not.

Comment: good idea; I tagged it featured so it'll show on the main site, too